# I need to get rid of the print statement while outputting the same thing. How can I change this code so there is zero print statements

Tags: python

```
  #Converts decimal to binary after the user inputs
 def Decimaltobinary(Decimal):
        #if user inputs 0 then it will return 0
        if Decimal == 0:
            #returns
            return 0
        #repeats if number is not 0
        else:
            #Decimal divided by 2
            Decimaltobinary(int(Decimal / 2))
            #i need to get rid of this print 
            print(Decimal % 2, end="")
            return str(Decimal)
            # Not sure how to change the print to a return while giving 
            the same output
            #input 2
            #Output 01
```

Comment: input/output...

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: could you give us an expected input and output for your code along with proper formatting?

Comment: Please be precise about what the function *outputs* versus what it *returns*; they are two *very* different things. The interactive interpreter muddles the distinction because it prints/outputs the value of an expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
def divide_Decimal():
    Decimal = Decimal / 2
    return str(Decimal)

divide_Decimal(#value_of_decimal)
```

If you are not allowed to use the `print` statement, you can define a function and use `return` instead, which has the same effect as `print` if you simply want to output a value.

Comment: I couldn't completely understand your code, so I'm just explaning how to use "return" to replace "print", and you can implement it into the code yourself. If this is helpful, pls upvote/accept. Thanks!!

Comment: Just posted another answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
def Decimaltobinary(Decimal):
    if Decimal == 0:
        return 0        
    else:       
        Decimaltobinary(int(Decimal / 2)) 
        var = str(Decimal % 2, end="")
        return var, str(Decimal)
```

Comment: You can return two values in a function by simply separating the two values with a comma.

Comment: i copied your code and Decimal % 2 is underlined red

Comment: Everything in that line in brackets is highlighted yellow and it says unexpected argument

Comment: Can you help future readers by adding some details please